# Swift3 Firebase retrieve data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling with getting some of the data from my Firebase. This is how the structure looks like:

[image]

This is the code I retrieve the data with:

```
var followDatesDict = [String:String]()

databaseRef.child("FollowGroups").child(selectedFollowGroupId as String).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if snapshot.hasChildren(){

                    let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "followgroupTitle").value as! String
                    let sDate = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "startDate").value as! String
                    let eDate = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "endDate").value as! String

                    followDatesDict = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "followDates")......



                }
            })
```

I can retrieve `name`, `sDate`, and `eDate` just fine. But does anyone know how I can fill up the `followDatesDict` ordered by date? As you see in the structure of `followDates`, the key is a String of dates and a String value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I managed to get the data. I also add them into a struct.

```
let enumerator = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "followDates").children
                    while let rest = enumerator.nextObject() as? FIRDataSnapshot {
                        let key_followDate = rest.key
                        let value_UserId = rest.value as! String

                        //add to dictionary
                        self.followDatesDict.insert(followgroupOverview(followDate:key_followDate, followUserId:value_UserId), at: 0)
                    }
```